# Passing arguments into WolframScript in batch mode

Tags: packages, scripting

I am looking for a way to passing arguments into a WL script when WL run in batch modes.
The test script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript

(*generate "num" samples of a mixed distribution*)
num = ToExpression[$ScriptCommandLine];
Print["num ", num];
Print /@ RandomVariate[
  MixtureDistribution[{1, 2}, {NormalDistribution[1, 0.2], 
    NormalDistribution[3, 0.1]}], num, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

The output file:

```
Mathematica 11.3.0 Kernel for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2018 Wolfram Research, Inc.
In[1]:= 
In[2]:= num {}

In[3]:= 
Out[3]= True


Out[4]= 1.2216923087229409686348818698669268506575506911553
```

And the `sh` script :

```
#!/bin/sh
#$ -cwd
/gpfs0/system/Mathematica/11.3/Executables/math < test.wls 3 > test_out.txt
```

It is looks that I do not succeed to pass the arguments to the script. Any suggestion on how to do it correctly?

Comment: Hmm, I think there are some fundamental misunderstandings going on here which make it difficult for me to understand what you even want to do. Can you give information on JUST 1) the code you want to run in the script, 2) what general arguments will look like/what form they're actually in? Then I'd be able to attempt a ground up solution.

Comment: (although showing what you've tried so far is always welcome and I don't want to discourage that)

Comment: thank you @user6014
I can't post my code, but I will try to explain my problem. 
I try to run simulations, and each instance of the simulation will process different instance of the dataset, each dataset has a different id (integer). 
I want an implement  'for'  in "sh" script and run all instances of the dataset, using one "sh" script. 
So it is the reason why I have to pass an integer from into WL script.

Comment: What does the data that is actually being passed look like? Is it a line in a file? Is each piece of data its own file?

Comment: @user6014 The data that will be passed is an integer. Yes, it is a line in code as such this "simulation=y" (I want to pass y into the file), each piece of data its unique file. I am using the parameter "y" as a unique identifier, and each simulation has a unique code, dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so this is what your script might want to look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript

num = ToExpression[$ScriptCommandLine[[2]]];

Export[
    "~/Desktop/wstest/test"<>DateString[{"Hour", "Minute", "Second", "MillisecondShort"}]<>".txt"
    ,
    RandomVariate[
        MixtureDistribution[{1, 2},
            {NormalDistribution[1, Rationalize[.2]], NormalDistribution[3, Rationalize[.1]]}
        ]
        ,
        num
        ,
        WorkingPrecision -> 50
    ]
    ,
    "CSV"
]
```

And you can call it with

```
test.wls 3
```

from your shell (a `chmod +x test.wls` might be necessary). The result is a .txt file in the specified folder (with a timestamp added to make it unique) of the form

```
2.945267726074665622104002146319038844277342932419
3.0059934477355789443483766777766852723094126818552
2.9593531823056876773610286479120461237403695981006
```

Your major mistakes:

1) `ToExpression[$ScriptCommandLine]` needs a position specifier to actually grab the specific argument

2) you were trying to run this script in the `math` executable. That's not needed, it can just run as its own executable against `wolframscript`

3) I think you were overcomplicating things with the `<` and `>` redirection. With the information you've provided so far, that shouldn't be necessary.

Let me know if you have got further questions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and sorry for the delay in response.
Please take a look at the `output file` to line 2,`num =ToExpression[$ScriptCommandLine]; Print["num ", num];`

 The `ToExpression[$ScriptCommandLine]` is empty, and I don't have any idea why I can't pass any argument to the script

Comment: I succeed to pass the arguments by using '$CommandLine'

Comment: @KirilDanilchenko So it all worked?

Comment: yes its work, thank you a lot

Comment: @KirilDanilchenko You can accept a correct answer !

Comment: I succeed to grab the argument by using '$CommandLine' rather than using '$ScriptCommandLine'. Please edit your answer according to that.
 I have yet to understand why this command should be used and not the command that appears in the tutorial.